# Can I use MenuStrip as ContextMenu?

Tags: .net, winforms, contextmenu, menustrip

Hi Ladies and Gentlemans!

I have a `MenuStrip` and want to have a `ContextMenu` with same structure.
Can I use my `MenuStrip` as `ContextMenu`, or quick create `ContextMenu` with DataSource from `MenuStrip`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not believe that you can use an item from a `MenuStrip` as a `ContextMenuStrip`. I've run into this before, and I agree that a menu should be a menu, but they're apparently implemented as different controls because they require slightly different functionality under the covers.

However, you *can* use a `ContextMenuStrip` as a drop-down menu for the `MenuStrip` control. So you can achieve the behavior you're looking for by doing it the other way around. Design the `ContextMenuStrip` however you want it, and then assign it to the [`DropDown` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdownitem.dropdown.aspx) for the top-level `ToolStripMenuItem` on the `MenuStrip` that you want that menu to be shown for.

Or, you can go the long way and create two different menus in the Designer, but copy-and-paste the items from one menu to the other. This at least saves you the time of designing two menus to look exactly the same. You can even wire up the event handlers (say, for the `Click` events of each menu item) to handle the items from both menus. In VB.NET, for example, the `Handles` keyword makes this extremely simple:

```
Private Sub Exit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
   Handles exitMenuItem.Click, exitContextMenuItem.Click
   Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked well for me. I don't recommend the copy-and-paste approach, because you'll forever have to keep the two menus in sync (a constant source of run-time bugs!)

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a short, to the point, answer: **No**.